# Scripting Macro for Outlook to Find a Folder

Tags: vba, vb.net, outlook

What's the best way to automate this function?

I want to be able to do this in Outlook 2010,

(1)select a specific mail account 
(2)Key in a folder that I am looking for 
(3)Then have the macro/program fire off an "*" asterisk 
(4)Then insert the text that I keyed in step one.

I am trying to automate the search for a folder hot-keys that already exist.

My problem is that I can't type the folder that I am looking for fast enough and all the search programs that I have used are far too slow. The hot-key search is awesome and super fast, I just can't type the folder that I am looking for fast enough. Can this process be automated?

Comment: Please show the actual code that you want to speed up. Are all these folder on the same level? Or are they nested?

Comment: They are nested.  I just need a way to completely type the folder then search.

Comment: 1. Expand all Outlook Folders:
   a. Highlight the PST file name in the "Mail Folders" box on the left, clicking until it is blue.
   b. Type <Num Lock><Numeric Pad-*>

2. Find the Folder:
   a. Begin typing the first few characters of folder name

Comment: I can't type fast enough to find the folder so I want a box that will allow me to type what I am looking for then do the press * <<Insert what is in the box>>.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code

```
Private m_Folder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Private m_Find As String
Private m_Wildcard As Boolean

Public Sub FindFolder()
  Dim Name$
  Dim Folders As Outlook.Folders

  Set m_Folder = Nothing
  m_Find = ""
  m_Wildcard = False

  Name = InputBox("Find Name:", "Search Folder")
  If Len(Trim$(Name)) = 0 Then Exit Sub
  m_Find = Name

  m_Find = LCase$(m_Find)
  m_Find = Replace(m_Find, "%", "*")
  m_Wildcard = (InStr(m_Find, "*"))

  Set Folders = Application.Session.Folders
  LoopFolders Folders

  If Not m_Folder Is Nothing Then
    If MsgBox("Activate Folder: " & vbCrLf & m_Folder.FolderPath, vbQuestion Or vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
      Set Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder = m_Folder
    End If
  Else
    MsgBox "Not Found", vbInformation
  End If
End Sub

Private Sub LoopFolders(Folders As Outlook.Folders)
  Dim F As Outlook.MAPIFolder
  Dim Found As Boolean

  For Each F In Folders
    If m_Wildcard Then
      Found = (LCase$(F.Name) Like m_Find)
    Else
      Found = (LCase$(F.Name) = m_Find)
    End If

    If Found Then
      Set m_Folder = F
      Exit For
    Else
      LoopFolders F.Folders
      If Not m_Folder Is Nothing Then Exit For
    End If
  Next
End Sub
```

Taken from http://www.vboffice.net/sample.html?mnu=2&smp=82&cmd=showitem&lang=en

Comment: No, this takes far to long and I have tried this.  I have over 2,500 folders that I am searching through, the what that I have requested is almost instantaneous - the code you posted takes over 2 minutes to find. :/

Answer (score 0):

Assuming "\" as a separator, you will need to split the folder name into a list or array of strings and then for each element recursively retrieve the next child folder. Similar to what basher suggested, but with one crucial difference - there is absolutely no reason to loop through all subfolders: Folders.Item in OOM takes either an integer index (1 through Count) or the subfolder name.

E.g. Subfolder = Folder.Folders.Item("Some name") will retrieve a subfolder named "Some name".

EDIT: Sample script (VBA):

```
strFolderPath = "Subfolder 1\Subfolder 2"
FolderNames = Split(strFolderPath, "\")
'aassuming the path is relative to the currently displayed folder
'or use a top level folder
set RootFolder = Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder
set CurrentFolder = RootFolder
for each subFolderName in FolderNames
  set CurrentFolder = CurrentFolder.Folders.Item(subFolderName)
next
Debug.Print CurrentFolder.Name
```

Comment: Could you please expound on this method/technique?  What would you do this in? VBA? AHK?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an improved version of the previously posted script. It continues searching, allowing you to skip some folders in order to get to the one you need (if there are multiple matches).

```vb
Private Const SpeedUp As Boolean = True

Public Sub FindFolder()
  Dim Name$
  Dim Folders As Outlook.Folders

  Dim findResult As Integer
  Dim m_Find As String
  Dim m_Wildcard As Boolean

  
  Set m_Folder = Nothing
  m_Find = ""
  m_Wildcard = False

  Name = InputBox("Find Name:", "Search Folder")
  If Len(Trim$(Name)) = 0 Then Exit Sub
  m_Find = Name

  m_Find = LCase$(m_Find)
  m_Find = Replace(m_Find, "%", "*")
  m_Wildcard = (InStr(m_Find, "*"))

  Set Folders = Application.Session.Folders
  findResult = LoopFolders(Folders, m_Find, m_Wildcard)

  If findResult = 0 Then
    MsgBox "Folder search complete", vbInformation
  End If
End Sub

Private Function LoopFolders(Folders As Outlook.Folders, m_Find As String, m_Wildcard As Boolean)
  Dim F As Outlook.MAPIFolder
  Dim Found As Boolean
  Dim findResult As Integer
  Dim anySubFolder As Boolean
  anySubFolder = False

  If SpeedUp = False Then DoEvents

  For Each F In Folders
    If m_Wildcard Then
      Found = (LCase$(F.Name) Like m_Find)
    Else
      Found = (LCase$(F.Name) = m_Find)
    End If

    If Found Then
      Dim msgBoxResult As Integer
      msgBoxResult = MsgBox("Activate Folder: " & vbCrLf & F.FolderPath & vbCrLf & "Yes to activate, No to continue search, Cancel to stop search", vbQuestion Or vbYesNoCancel)
      If msgBoxResult = vbYes Then
        Set Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder = F
        LoopFolders = 1
      ElseIf msgBoxResult = vbCancel Then
        LoopFolders = 2
        Exit Function
      End If
    Else
      findResult = LoopFolders(F.Folders, m_Find, m_Wildcard)
      If findResult > 0 Then
        LoopFolders = findResult
        Exit Function
      End If
    End If
  Next
  LoopFolders = 0
End Function
```